# Unable to locate database.mdf in production server

Tags: sql-server

1) I want to attach a database from my development server to my production server.

The database `ESpiceHerbs` from my development server is located at:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA
```

2) When I log in using my production server credentials and right click on the `Databases` folder in `Object Explorer` and select `Attach Databases` and click `Add`,  I cannot find it there! :(

[image: http://imageshack.us/f/341/msuservercannotlocate.jpg/]

3) I am really confused as to why it cannot be located although its pointing to the same folder.

Could it be because the development server is running on 32 bit and the production server is running on 64 bit?

[image: http://imageshack.us/f/259/differencessql.jpg/]

Comment: So have you detached the .mdf from your dev server, and copied it to the production server??? In order to attach it, the `.mdf` file (and any additional `.ndf` and `.ldf` files that make up the database) **must** be on the production server's local disks (or a UNC path the server can get to)

Answer (score 2):

Might be a rights issue. Have a look at the security settings on the physical .mdf file and make sure the user you are using for SSMS has access to that .mdf file.

Most probably, as you are supplying credentials, you are logging on with your Windows user id, so make sure that you have read-write priviliges on the .mdf file.

To get to the security settings:
Explore -> Locate your file -> Right click -> Properties -> Security Tab

Your user group or your user should be in that list.

Comment: @marc_s Marc_s You hit the jackpot. I knew it must be some silly mistake or something that went pass my mind. Do you mind explaining more about the UNC Path? 
The url i provided at step (2) is that of the production server which i dont have access to. But i know the person who does. Does it mean that everytime i want to update my database, i have to give him the file and ask him to replace the existing database.mdf with the updated database.mdf? Aren't there any more convenient methods to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
change the extension menu to *.* files.
```

[image]

Comment: I"m sorry but I'm afraid i dont quite comprehend that answer. Could you please be more specific? Thank you :)

Comment: @user1079650 see my edit - change the value so you can see all files.

Comment: @ Royi Namir. I did. Still unable to locate the files.